# Loading dynamic content based on hash or query string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going to create a single page javascript application. It will load different page content based on the url being modified, either by the hash or the html history API depending on the browser.

My though was to use this [plugin](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API) in order to have the hash fallback for older browsers.

```
var location = window.history.location || window.location;

handleUrlChange(location.href);

$(document).on('click', 'a.ajax', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.pushState(null, null, this.href);
    handleUrlChange(this.href);
});

$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
    handleUrlChange(location.href);      
});

function handleUrlChange(url){
     // example url: www.foo.com?page=details&id=1
     var page = getQueryStringParam('page') || 'index';
     $('#dynamic-content').load(page + '.html');
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
    <body>
         <div id="header"></div>
         <div id="dynamic-content"></div>
         <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is if there are any frameworks that already does this? I don't want to re-invent the wheel here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of solutions, like:

1. https://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/
2. http://stoodder.github.io/finchjs/
3. http://backbonejs.org/#Router
4. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

You can choose what's fits you most. If you don't want to use backbone features like models or collections, or angular framework, and you need just routing, use crossroads.js or finch.js, or just type in google: "Javascript routing" to find other libraries.

Personally, I used only backbone routing.

http://backbonejs.org/#Router

It's easy to use, automatically checks if History API can be used, if not, it uses hash navigation.

Comment: Thanks, I found https://github.com/flatiron/director which seems nice. Do I need to download the entire backbone library in order to make use of its router?

Comment: Yes in order to use backbone routers, you need entire backbone library, plus underscore and jquery which backbone depends on.